# How to calculate percent variation

Tags: frequency, coefficient-of-variation

I've came across a method in research communication, where different percentages of variation were calculated for a collection of ratio values for some proteins. As seen in the figure, the frequency of (protein) ratios falling within a certain percentage of variation is plotted against the percent variation itself.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgXkC.jpg]

Can anyone tell me how this percent variation is calculated?

Comment: We need more information than what is on the graph in your link to help answer the question.

Comment: Hint: the data counts are 24,5,4,1,2,1,1,0,1,1. The *cumulative* counts therefore are 24,29,33,34,36,37,38,38,39,40.  What do you get when you re-express those cumulative counts as percentages of the total (40)?

Comment: @whuber: Do you mean: dat<-c(24,29,33,34,36,37,38,38,39,40);
(dat/40)*100                                         which gives: 60.0  72.5  82.5  85.0  90.0  92.5  95.0  95.0  97.5 100.0

Comment: Yes! More generally, starting with the data in the bars (`x<-seq(0.1,1.0,0.1); y<-c(24,5,4,1,2,1,1,0,1,1)`), 
compute `plot(100*x, 100*cumsum(y)/sum(y), ylim=c(0,100))` and compare that to your graph.  How does it look?

Comment: @whuber  Thanks, but I've found in another paper by the same author where percent variation is replaced by percent CV(coeff. of variation)  ![image](http://imageshack.us/a/img837/2792/49245955.png)  I'm still not sure what does percentage of CV mean.  The details can be found [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/pr100759a/suppl_file/pr100759a_si_003.pdf)

Comment: You can [look up the meaning of CV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation).